# Ruby: How do I change the value of a parameter in a function call?

Tags: ruby

How would I impelement a function, in ruby, such as the following?

```
change_me! (val)
```

**update**:

What I set out to do was this:

```
def change_me! (val)
  val = val.chop while val.end_with? '#' or val.end_with? '/'
end
```

This just ended up with....

```
change_me! 'test#///'     => "test#///"
```

Comment: What you are trying to do screws with scope. When you call a function, you change scope, so it won't work the way you want it to. You'd need to play with 'define_method', which is overkill for this. You need to refactor your thought process.

Comment: @Trevoke What zombies tries would be possible with pass-by-pointer or pass-by-reference. However, ruby does not do that. You can modify the inside of the passed object, but not the object itself. But you can completely replace what's stored in the object.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You're thinking about this the wrong way around. While it may be possible to do this in Ruby, it would be overly complicated. The proper way to do this would be:

```
val.change_me!
```

Which, of course, varies depending on the class of what you want to change. The point is that, by convention, the methods with '!' affect the class instance on which they're called.
So...

```
class Changeable
  def initialize var
    @var = var
  end

  def change_me! change=1
    @var += change
  end
end

a = Changeable.new 5 # => New object "Changeable", value 5
a.change_me! 6 # => @var = 7
a.change_me! # => @var = 8
```

Hope this helps a bit..

Comment: this wont work for all parameter type, for example arrays or hashes

Comment: ennuikiller: you are right. I just want to illustrate the idea.

Comment: This `Changeable` could be a module with only the `change_me!` method.  Then, you can `include` it into a class definition or `extend` an individual object.

Comment: @glenn : you are right! But now we just move further and further away from the exact question, and soon we'll be talking about the phase of the moon.. :)

Comment: @ennuikiller, that is not true: it will definitely work for Arrays and Hashes. Look up `Array#replace` and `Hash#replace` in `ri`.

Answer (score 10):

You want to do this:

```
def change_me(val)
  val.replace "#{val}!"
end
```

This replaces the value with a new one. But trust me: You don't usually want to design your ruby code in such a way. Start thinking in objects and classes. Design your code free of side-effects. It will save a whole lot of trouble.

Comment: This makes me shiver and reminds me of the bug in COBOL where you could change the value of 1 to be 2.
It is quite close to what the OP asked for though :)

Comment: @Trevoke luckily Ruby is not affected by this bug, although it would be interesting to generate stuff like 2+2=5 ;-)

Comment: @hurikhan77, that is easy to do: `class Fixnum; alias :old_+ :+; def +(other); self == 2 && other == 2 ? 5 : old_+(other); end end`

Comment: @AlexD I know... ;-) But that is still different from the old COBOL bug where you could replace the value of 3 to be something else.

Answer (score 3):

What kind of object is `val` and how do you want to change it? If you just want to mutate an object (say, an array or a string), what you are asking for works directly:

```
def change_me!(me)
    me << 'abides'
end 

val = %w(the dude)
change_me!(val)
puts val.inspect

val = "the dude "
change_me!(val)
puts val.inspect
```

Comment: So what I am really asking is how to mutate objects. Rather, write my own method that mutates an object...

Comment: Also, `me += 'abides'` doesn't work, even if it looks like it should (for ruby newbies).